# Query Postgresql admin privileges

Tags: database, postgresql, security, admin, privileges

For example I give  CREATE priviliges on Postgresql database to Public

postgres=# GRANT CREATE

postgres-#     ON DATABASE postgres

postgres-#     TO public   ;

GRANT

Or I can give such admin privileges at Postgresql database to any roles or any users

My questions is ; How can I query which users or roles have any admin priviliges 
for  Postgresql database security control

Thanks in advance

Anil Akduygu

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that admin access is a pretty vague term.  Admin access for what?

- pg_database.datacl stores the permissions for a database
- pg_class.relacl stores the permissions for a relation
- Similar fields exist in many other system atalogs

On top of this you want to look at ownership and user implications so pg_roles is important.